# Vulkan Validation layers don't work with the Error and Warning flags on Linux

Tags: c++, validation, vulkan

I have run into a problem where when i was setting the flags for my `VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT` struct, the error, `VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT`, warning, information and performance flags do not activate my callback, but the debug flag did, `VK_DEBUG_REPORT_DEBUG_BIT_EXT`. Does anyone know what the problem could be for that behavior? I am using Clion

a link to relevent code: https://pastebin.com/y9bUciCT

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: I added the link to the instantiation of the vulkan debug callback, the callback function, as well as which validation layer i'm using.

Comment: Do you have the extension enabled?

Comment: Yes, i even check to see if the layer i'm requesting is part of the extensions

Comment: um, what? I mean if you passed `VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME` (resp. `"VK_EXT_debug_report"`) to `ppEnabledExtensionNames` of `vkCreateInstance`?

Comment: I Solved the issue by putting all the json files for the layer in my .local/vulkan file